# How to enable language navigation for content?

Tags: mediawiki

How can I enable the language links on my MedaiWiki install? The one I am talking about is the one that spans the bottom of the page and starts with [Language: English, French, etc...)

Just to be clear, it is the language navigation stuff directly under the download button on the homepage for MediaWiki.

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a feature built into MediaWiki, it is done with templates and parser functions. If you want something similar, you could copy their [Template:Languages](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Template%3aLanguages) and related templates.

Comment: thanks. I wish they made this a little more obvious in the documentation